# Modify File Stream in memory

Tags: c#

I am reading a file using `StreamReader fileReader = File.OpenText(filePath)`. I would like to modify one line in the file in memory and push the modified stream to another method.

What I would like to avoid is reading the whole file into a string and modifying the string (doesn't scale). I would also like to avoid modifying the actual file.

Is there a straightforward way of doing this?

Comment: You can create wrapper StreamReader and update data as you need for every operation after calling wrapped reader.

Comment: That is my backup plan. I was hoping there was a built-in way of doing this.

Comment: No, there is no filtering readers in .Net Framework.

Comment: Put it as an answer and i'll select it, if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do that in .Net framework.

`Stream` and `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter` classes are designed to be chained if necessary (like `GZipStream` wraps stream to compress it). So you can create wrapper StreamReader and update data as you need for every operation after calling wrapped reader.

Answer (score 0):

You can open two stream -one for read, one for write- at the same time. I tested simple code that works, but not sure that's what you want:

```
// "2.bar\r\n" will be replaced by "!!!!!\r\n"
File.WriteAllText("test.txt", 
@"1.foo
2.bar
3.fake");

// open inputStream for StreamReader, and open outputStream for StreamWriter
using (var inputStream = File.Open("test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
using (var outputStream = File.Open("test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(outputStream))
{
    var position = 0L; // track the reading position
    var newLineLength = Environment.NewLine.Length;
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        // your particular conditions here.
        if (line.StartsWith("2."))
        {
            // seek line start position
            outputStream.Seek(position, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            // replace by something, 
            // but the length should be equal to original in this case.
            writer.WriteLine(new String('!', line.Length));
        }
        position += line.Length + newLineLength;
    }
}
/* as a result, test.txt will be:
1.foo
!!!!!
3.fake
*/
```

As you can see, both streams can be accessed by StreamReader and StreamWriter at the same time. And you can also manipulate both read/write position as well.